# how to stop Infinite loop when adding translations to Flutter text in stateful widget

Tags: flutter, stateful

I am trying to add dynamic translation to text in a stateful widget. (Maybe there is a better approach to this)

I have a function that retrieves a translation from the google api for each Text in my Flutter app.  The problem is that neither "drawer" nor "expansionTile" have an ontap(extended does have an 'on expansion changed')  that I can use so I have tried to create a "oneshot" approach by only enabling the function and setState if the language is changed but it seems like a bit of a kludge.  There has to be a better way.  And as it has to look up each one sequentially it becomes quite slow.  Is there any way to do a complete conversion of all Text widgets in the background and store it? Do I need to build a map?  Might get real messy real fast though.  Gotta be something I am missing.

The whole widget is pretty big so I have just included the relevant code here.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //call check wifi connection
  bool _wifi = false;
  bool _isButtonDisabled = false;
  String _textTranslated = "no translation";
  String _languageSelected = "en";
  String _oldLanguageSelected;
  Map<String,String> _getLanguageList; // roughed in for getting google languages

  Future<bool> _translate(text)  async {
    // capture translation so that it will not keep looping when no new language is selected

    if(_languageSelected == _oldLanguageSelected){
      print('languages match');
      return true;
    }else{
    _oldLanguageSelected = _languageSelected;
    print("translate input: $text");
    // TODO add wifi check
    final translator = new GoogleTranslator();
    final textTranslated = await translator.translate(text, to: '$_languageSelected');

    setState(() {
      print('Translation is $textTranslated');
      _textTranslated = textTranslated;
      return true;
    });
      //_textTranslated = text;
      print('translated output: $_textTranslated');        
      return true; 
    }

  }
```

And here is my drawer:

```
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[

        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('Select a New Language\n(RB Experimental)',textAlign: TextAlign.center, textScaleFactor: 1.2, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900])),
          children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(              
            leading: Container(height: 30, width: 60,  child: Image.asset('images/flags/nl.png')),
            title: Text('Dutch'),
            trailing: Text("code: nl"),
            onTap:() async { print("Selecting nl language"); 

              _languageSelected = "nl";
              //_translate('test nl string');        
              Navigator.pop(context,true);  // close drawer                     
          },                  
        ),
          ListTile(              
            leading: Container(height: 30, width: 60, child: Image.asset('images/flags/fr.png')),         //Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.signLanguage),
            title: Text('French'),
            trailing: Text("code: fr"),
            onTap:() { print("Selecting fr language");          
              _languageSelected = "fr"; 
              _translate('test fr string');       
              Navigator.pop(context,true);  // close drawer             
          },                            
        ),
```

And here is where I call the _translate function in the body

```
body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 150.0),//(25.0),
              child:  _translate('Configuration Tool') != null?  Text('$_textTranslated ',
              textScaleFactor: 1.5,):Text('no translation'),
            ),
```

And finally my Future function in my NetworkUtilities class:

```
class NetworkUtilities {

  static Future<Map<String,String>> getGoogleLanguageList() async{
    //  https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages

    print('Ping google translate api for its language list');

    //TODO get this list from Google
    final translations = {'Dutch':'nl', 'French': 'fr', 'German':'de', 'Italian':'it', 'Spanish':'es', 'Default to English':'en'};
    return(translations);
  }
```

And this is the output from terminal for my prints:

```
I/flutter ( 9874): Selecting fr language
I/flutter ( 9874): languages match
I/flutter ( 9874): Selecting de language
I/flutter ( 9874): translate input: test de string
I/flutter ( 9874): Translation is Test de Zeichenfolge
I/flutter ( 9874): translated output: Test de Zeichenfolge
I/flutter ( 9874): languages match
I/flutter ( 9874): Selecting de language
I/flutter ( 9874): languages match
I/flutter ( 9874): Selecting it language
I/flutter ( 9874): translate input: test it string
I/flutter ( 9874): Translation is Test si stringa
I/flutter ( 9874): translated output: Test si stringa
I/flutter ( 9874): languages match
```

Answer (score 0):

After asking the question and putting words to screen it became pretty obvious that this is not the way to go for translations, as it is just too slow.  Instead I am going to go to a static model and map out all of my Text widgets into an indexed list.